# DocuSign Electronic Signature : On signature window getting error "This authentication mode is not supported: NONE" ("Standards Based Signatures")

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using Docusign API with a demo account. the signer gets this error on the signature:

> This authentication mode is not supported: NONE

After doing some research I found that it's related to SBS ("Standards Based Signatures").

the problem is I can't found a way to make it work. Can someone help, please?

[image]

Comment: Is this for Captive Signing? If so, can we see your RecipientViewRequest?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention was to use Standards Based Signature in addition to eSignature, you may need to do additional work to get this working as well as ensure your account is configured/set up to use this feature.

Example of the JSON (taken from [the page on this topi](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/standards-based-signatures/)c)

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "routingOrder": 1,
      "name": "Sue Collins",
      "email": "sue@example.com",
      "deliveryMethod": "email",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "recipientSignatureProviders": [
        {
          "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP",
          "signatureProviderOptions": {
            "oneTimePassword": "{YOUR_PASSWORD}"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "routingOrder": 2,
      "name": "Yan",
      "email": "jim@me.com",
      "deliveryMethod": "email",
      "recipientId": "2",
      "recipientSignatureProviders": [
        {
          "signatureProviderName": "UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP",
          "signatureProviderOptions": {
            "sms": "+13303103330"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```